# Polymer/Lit-Element - Braintree gateway integration - Web Component problem

Tags: polymer, vaadin, vaadin14

I am trying to integrate Braintree payment gateway to Vaadin 14 which is using Polymer for its frontend.

Basically we have a custom Vaadin front-end view to load script *https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.9.4/js/dropin.min.js* :

And we call its method **dropin.create** as below:

```js
import{PolymerElement}from'@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import'@polymer/iron-icon/iron-icon.js';
import{html}from'@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/html-tag.js';
import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js';
import'@polymer/polymer/polymer-legacy.js';
import'@polymer/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.js';


import{mixinBehaviors}from'@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/class.js';
import{Polymer}from'@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/polymer-fn.js';
import{setTouchAction}from'@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/gestures.js';
import{afterNextRender}from'@polymer/polymer/lib/utils/render-status.js';
import'@vaadin/vaadin-text-field/vaadin-text-field.js';

import { sharedStyles } from './drop-in.js';

let dropin = require('braintree-web-drop-in');

class BrainTreeVaadin extends PolymerElement {

    <vaadin-vertical-layout class="main-div-layout-boder padding5">
        <form id="paymentForm" method="post" action="/checkout" class="main-screen-vert-layout-row">
            <div id="containPayment" class="main-screen-vert-layout-row">
                <div id="btDropin" class="main-screen-vert-layout-row"></div>
            </div>
            <vaadin-text-field id="nonce" value={{valueNonce}} hidden></vaadin-text-field>
            <vaadin-button id="butPayment" theme="theme-button-02" class="button-row">Payment</vaadin-button>
        </form>
    </vaadin-vertical-layout>

createFormPayment(){

let form = this.$.paymentForm;
let butPayment = this.$.butPayment;
let btDropin =  this.$.btDropin;
let textNonce = this.$.nonce;

dropin.create({
  authorization: this.clientToken,
  container: btDropin,
  card: {
    cardholderName: {
        required: true
    }
  },
  paypal: {
     flow: 'vault',
     currency: 'USD'
  },
  paypalCredit: {
     flow: 'vault',
     currency: 'USD'
  }
}
}
}
```

However we get error as below image:

[image: error]

Reason that internally, the main script **dropin.min.js** includes other script **https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.min.js** and called other methods from this new JS.

Accessing methods in **checkout.min.js**  got error because **checkout.min.js** can’t get id of html elements (here is buttons) using javascript reference style "#...".

Braintree uses JS style *#element_id* to pass a html div element as argument to method: braintree.dropin.create(..., container: '#bt-dropin').

Below is Braintree example code (take note on method "*braintree.dropin.create*", it takes '*#bt-dropin*' as input):

```html
 <div class="bt-drop-in-wrapper">
    <div id="bt-dropin"></div>
 </div>

<div th:include="fragments/homefooter :: footer"></div>
        <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/web/dropin/1.9.4/js/dropin.min.js"></script>
        <script th:inline="javascript">
            /*<![CDATA[*/
            var form = document.querySelector('#payment-form');
            var client_token = [[${clientToken}]];
        
            braintree.dropin.create({
              authorization: client_token,
              container: '#bt-dropin',
              paypal: {
                flow: 'vault'
              }
            }, function (createErr, instance) {
              form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  $('#errorDiv').hide();
                  $('#serverSideErrorDiv').hide();
                  
                  instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
                    if (err) {
                      console.log('Error', err);
                      showError(err);
                      return;
                    }
            
                    // Add the nonce to the form and submit
                    document.querySelector('#nonce').value = payload.nonce;
                    form.submit();
                  });
              });
            });
```

And problem that Vaadin form (view) doesn’t understand javascript style: **"#bt-dropin"** to reference to a div element.

**How to make Vaadin view understand JS style: "#element_id"** ?

**Update:**
this is polymer problem, not Vaadin flow problem.

**Update 2:**
this is braintree problem, not polymer problem :)).

Answer (score 0):

This is a issue of braintree due to lacking of supporting web components.
Below is workaround solution.

[Braintree Git Issue](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web-drop-in/issues/296)

**Workaround** (remove space  .io on URL):

```
https://codepen .io/braintree/pen/VrYXYW
```